# bash heredoc inside a vagrant vm provision heredoc

Tags: ruby, heredoc, vagrant-provision

I like to use a bash heredoc inside the ruby heredoc from config.vm.provision, like so:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    cat >> foobar <<EOF
    bla bla
    foo foo
EOF
echo 'some other command'
SHELL
```

But when the privision file is executed, everything to the end of the provision ends up in `foobar`.
I suspect that I need some escaping here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you insist on the nested heredocs? What’s wrong with:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: %q|
    cat >> foobar <<EOF
    bla bla
    foo foo
EOF
echo 'some other command'
|
```

Comment: So you've swapped a heredoc for value .  Isn't the heredoc supplying a similar ephemeral value?  Please help me understand how %q|[something]| won't have the same issue when we use a pipe symbol in the bash script.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with the indents. This is the revised version of your code, which works as you intend.

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  {{...}}
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-'SHELL'
    cat >> foobar <<EOF
bla bla
foo foo
EOF
    echo 'some other command'
  SHELL
end
```